# Error while running python manage py migrate

Tags: python, mysql, django, xampp

I am new to django, I was running  the command

```
python manage.py migrate
```

and got this error.

> (py1) G:\django\djangoproject1>python manage.py migrate Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 22, in 
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "C:\Users\Mahin\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 364, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "C:\Users\Mahin\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 356, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\Users\Mahin\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 283, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "C:\Users\Mahin\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 327, in execute
>       self.check()   File "C:\Users\Mahin\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 359, in check
>       include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,   File "C:\Users\Mahin\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py",
>   line 61, in _run_checks
>       issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])   File "C:\Users\Mahin\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py",
>   line 81, in run_checks
>       new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)   File "C:\Users\Mahin\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\database.py",
>   line 10, in check_database_backends
>       issues.extend(conn.validation.check(**kwargs))   File "C:\Users\Mahin\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\validation.py",
>   line 9, in check
>       issues.extend(self._check_sql_mode(**kwargs))   File "C:\Users\Mahin\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\validation.py",
>   line 13, in _check_sql_mode
>       with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:   File "C:\Users\Mahin\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py",
>   line 254, in cursor
>       return self._cursor()   File "C:\Users\Mahin\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py",
>   line 229, in _cursor
>       self.ensure_connection()   File "C:\Users\Mahin\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py",
>   line 213, in ensure_connection
>       self.connect()   File "C:\Users\Mahin\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line
>   94, in **exit**
>       six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)   File "C:\Users\Mahin\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py",
>   line 213, in ensure_connection
>       self.connect()   File "C:\Users\Mahin\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py",
>   line 189, in connect
>       self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)   File "C:\Users\Mahin\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py",
>   line 274, in get_new_connection
>       conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)   File "C:\Users\Mahin\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb__init__.py", line
>   84, in Connect
>       return Connection(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Mahin\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py",
>   line 164, in **init**
>       super(Connection, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs2) django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

Comment: Isn't it self explanatory? MySQL credentials are not ok.

Comment: `"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"`

Comment: where should I change this?

Answer (score 2):

Since I should have magically known your settings.py DB config and my post was deleted for not answering the question without "requiring clarification from the asker" I'm reposting to try and help. The default password for root user in a mysql db is "", that is its left blank. Right now there is a mismatch between your db and the configuration you provided in your settings.py file. Go into your dbms and make sure that the setting for the database match the ones you provided in your settings.py.

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': 'DB NAME',
            'USER': 'USER NAME',
            'PASSWORD':'USER PW',
            'HOST' : 'localhost',
        }
    }
```

If these match to your db you should be able to now migrate.

Comment: try with 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost